# Building a React Component that can be both Controlled and Uncontrolled

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get my head around the difference between controlled and uncontrolled react components, so thought i would have a go at building a control that can be either but not both. It seems like the pattern used by `<input>` is that if you provide a `value` prop then it will be controlled, otherwise uncontrolled and you can provide a default value to uncontrolled using `defaultValue` prop.

My example control is a simple number incrementer/decrementer with buttons to increment and decrement and a label showing the current value.

My questions are .

1. Have I gone about this the right way.
2. I have written a number of tests to cover all the scenarios i can think of, are these all valid and am i missing any.

I am hoping through this example and any feedback to get a thorough understanding of controlled vs uncontrolled, and when to use each.

My code and all the tests are available in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-archimedes-cs0qy

but my component is repeated here for ease ...

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";

    export const NumberInput = ({ onChange, value, defaultValue, min, max }) => {
      const [uncontrolledVal, setUncontrolledVal] = useState(
        defaultValue || min || 0
      );

      if (
        (value && (value > max || value < min)) ||
        (defaultValue && (defaultValue > max || defaultValue < min))
      ) {
        throw new Error("Value out of range");
      }

      const handlePlusClick = () => {
        if (value && onChange) {
          onChange(value + 1);
        } else {
          const newValue = uncontrolledVal + 1;
          setUncontrolledVal(newValue);
          if (onChange) {
            onChange(newValue);
          }
        }
      };
      const handleMinusClick = () => {
        if (value && onChange) {
          onChange(value - 1);
        } else {
          const newValue = uncontrolledVal - 1;
          setUncontrolledVal(newValue);
          if (onChange) {
            onChange(newValue);
          }
        }
      };
      return (
        <>
          <button
            data-testid="decrement"
            disabled={value ? value === min : uncontrolledVal === min}
            onClick={() => handleMinusClick()}
          >
            {"-"}
          </button>
          <span className="mx-3 font-weight-bold">{value || uncontrolledVal}</span>
          <button
            data-testid="increment"
            disabled={value ? value === max : uncontrolledVal === max}
            onClick={() => handlePlusClick()}
          >
            {"+"}
          </button>
        </>
      );
    };
```

Comment: Its pretty easy: `controlled` inputs are meant to be fully controlled by you, you handle every change, thats why you need to pass `value` and `onChange`. `value` will represent what is being rendered on screen (probably a value from your state or prop from container) and `onChange` to handle every change, so you choose to update yours state that is passed to `value` or not. On `uncontrolled`, you just mind about setting an initial value via `defaultValue` and get the value when needed, you don't mind about its changes and how they are handled.

Comment: Ok think I got that, and fairly sure my example component satisfies both, but when would one use uncontrolled over controlled?

Comment: Lets say we have a form with some inputs that are pretty open and we don't need to validate them before hand, then we can leave all inputs as uncontrolled and just get the value when user submits the form. Per example, if there is one field named "Name", we don't need to care about every change that happens inside this field, just about the final value. Using uncontrolled makes the code a little bit smaller and avoid having to write handle functions for your inputs. That said, sometimes it's just a personal choice of what to use. Personally I prefer to use controlled inputs, but its my choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like this, a custom incrementer, there is no such thing as an uncontrolled version.  Uncontrolled applies to the built in input fields in HTML 5, such as a text field, a checkbox, or a file upload.

Controlled means the value of an input is set by a state or prop value and updated with a custom function. uncontrolled means it handles its own changes for its value and you have to manually retrieve their values when you want to use them.

This can be accomplished using something like a ref.

If you bind the value of an input field to a value without providing a function to update its value onChange, it will not respond to any user input.  However you can provide a defaultValue to it, and it will still respond to user input.

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Not sure I understand why there is no such thing as uncontrolled component. My implementation seems to satisfy those conditions. If there is a use case for uncontrolled html 5 inputs, is there not one for custom controls too. Just trying to understand what that use case is.

Comment: The thing is, html 5 inputs function on their own, without controlling them.  There are reasons why you might want to leave them that way (which are mentioned in that link I posted).  There is no reason to make your own uncontrolled components because it makes them simply nonfunctional.

Comment: Ok think it makes sense, so I was creating a wizard for creating a new object and using uncontrolled inputs to make sure my new object state was only updated with valid data. Instead I should allow invalid data in my state but prevent the state from being submitted or the wizard progresses if fields on certain page have invalid data. When initializing the wizard I should provide a model with default or empty values ? What about optional fields, fairly sure I read somewhere if I initialize an input with undefined value it will behave uncontrolled and not respond to future prop changes?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by invalid data, do you mean incorrect data types or something like values that don't match what the wizard will accept?  Generally though, it is generally best to provide your inputs with the value prop, tied to an outside state (even if you just initialize it with something like an empty string.  Then you should update that state with a React event listener.  And finally you should validate that the inputs are correct either when progressing with the wizard or when finally submitting it.